# Feign Retry with App properties only not with CustomRetryable class or using @Bean method to provide default retry mechanism

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openfeign

I am trying to leverage Feign's retry mechanism without custom retryable class or default retry.

The idea is to leverage Feign Retry only with the application.properties like below

`feign.client.config.default.readTimeout: 5000 feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout: 5000 feign.client.config.default.maxAttempts: 3 feign.client.config.default.maxPeriod: 10000 feign.client.config.default.period: 1000000`

This is some how not working for me. However, when i just add the following default retryable in the configurations class it works but I do not want to leverage it that way. I just want to leverage the appplication. properties to perform retries

Default Retry code which works just fine, but I do not want to use it.

`@Bean`

`public Retryer retryer()`

`{          return new Retryer.Default(10000, 100000, 3);`

`}` 
Below are my classes

1.Application.properties

`server.port=1000`

`feign.client.config.default.readTimeout: 5000`
`feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout: 5000`
`feign.client.config.default.maxAttempts: 3`
`feign.client.config.default.maxPeriod: 10000`
`feign.client.config.default.period: 1000000`

2. FeignClient

   package org.example;

   import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
   import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

   @FeignClient(url = "http://localhost:6000",value = "tealium-client", name="tealium-client") public interface ExampleFeignClient{
   @GetMapping("/test")
   public ResponseEntity sayHello();}

3. Controller class

```
package org.example;
import feign.FeignException; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@RestController public class TestController {
@Autowired
ExampleFeignClient exampleFeignClient;

AtomicInteger atomicInteger;

@GetMapping("/api/v1/hello")
public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = exampleFeignClient.sayHello();
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello, " + response);
}}
```

My question is, it should work just fine with configurations in application.properties just like database configurations or any other for that matter.

Cheers

I tried with application.properties which did not work but with default retryable it worked which I cannot use.

I am using openfeign.

Comment: My bad there is an = instead of : in the properties.